# Three IF statement in Excel

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I need to write an IF function to do the following. I have two parameters:

```
A: x
B: x

If "A1" is "x" and "B1" is "" -> "1"
If "B1" is "x" and "A1" is "" -> "2"
If "A1" and "B1" is "x" -> "3"
If in "A1" and "B1 is nothing -> "4"
```

I came up with this function, but it doesn't work correctly:

```
=IF(A1="x";"1";IF(B1="x";"2";IF(A1="x";"3";"4")))
```

Comment: what if B1 is "C", "42" or "etc"  that case is not reflected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work: `=IF(AND(A1="x",B1="x"),"3",IF(AND(A1="x",B1=""),"1",IF(AND(A1="",B1="x"),"2","4")))`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(A1="x",B1=""),1,IF(AND(B1="x",A1=""),2,IF(AND(A1="x",B1="x"),3,4)))
```

**EDIT** puts a blank in case of none of the stated inputs:

```
=IF(AND(A1="x",B1=""),1,IF(AND(B1="x",A1=""),2,IF(AND(A1="x",B1="x"),3,IF(AND(A1="",B1=""),4,""))))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
=1+MOD(LEN(A1&B1&B1)+3,4)
```

Comment: yes it is nice, but so far none of the formulas cover the case of what to do when a value other than X or "" is not present.  then again OP has not stated that either.  You will also need to substitute ";" in for the "," do to differences in operating systems.